# How to Replace "url says" with "name of web application says" in JavaScript Error Pop-Up

Tags: javascript, user-interface, error-handling, customization

I'm encountering an issue with JavaScript error messages displayed in my web application. Specifically, I want to replace the "url says" part of the error pop-up with "name of web application says" to enhance the user experience.

**Problem Description:**
When an error occurs in my web application, the browser displays a default error message that includes the URL where the error occurred, like this:

https://example.com/somepage.html says: Error Message

**Desired Outcome:**
I aim to customize this error message to be more user-friendly by replacing "https://example.com/somepage.html says" with "MyWebApp says." For example:

MyWebApp says: Error Message

**Request for Assistance:**
I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve this customization in JavaScript. If you have any insights, code snippets, or suggestions on how to replace "url says" with "name of web application says" in the error pop-up, please share them.

Here is my current JavaScript attempt:

```
// Get the current web application name
const webAppName = "MyWebApp"; // Replace with your web application's name

// Custom error handler
function customErrorHandler(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
    // Create a custom error message
    const customErrorMessage = `${webAppName} says: ${message}`;
    
    // Display the custom error message
    console.error(customErrorMessage);

    // Prevent the default browser error handling
    return true;
}

// Set the custom error handler for the entire window
window.addEventListener('error', customErrorHandler);

// Replace the default browser error message
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
    // Create a custom error message
    const customErrorMessage = `${webAppName} says: ${message}`;
    
    // Display the custom error message
    console.error(customErrorMessage);

    // Prevent the default browser error handling
    return true;
}
```

Thank you for your help and expertise.